# TFS 2015 Builds giving error after migrating from 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We have migrated from TFS 2012 to TFS 2015, after migrating our builds are not working. We are getting the below error.
I could not find much on internet on this.
Please help.

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Cockpit\DB.Dev.MetadataDB.Build: 
Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type FileNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace: at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(AssemblyName an, Evidence securityEvidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(String partialName)
at System.Activities.Expressions.AssemblyReference.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
at System.Activities.Expressions.AssemblyReference.GetAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicHelper.Initialize(HashSet`1 refAssemNames, HashSet`1 namespaceImportsNames)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicHelper.Compile[T](String expressionText, CodeActivityPublicEnvironmentAccessor publicAccessor, Boolean isLocationExpression)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicValue`1.CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.OnInternalCacheMetadataExceptResult(Boolean createEmptyBindings)
at System.Activities.Activity`1.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings)
at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors)
at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining, ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback)
at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.InternalActivityValidationServices.InternalValidate()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers.ValidateWorkflow(Activity activity, ValidationSettings validationSettings)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildProcessCache.LoadFromXaml(String workflowXaml, TextExpressionImports textExpressionImports)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
Inner Exception Details:
Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type FileNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your customized XAML file and make sure any reference to `Version=11.0.0, PublicKeyToken=123445` is removed. Just mention the Assembly by it's simple name. That allows Team Build to load the version that matches the version of the build server.

If you're lucky the old customizations are binary compatible, but in the worst case you'll need to recompile them against the current version of the TFS CLient Object Model.

See also:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpricket/2012/07/17/tfs-2012-cleaning-up-workflow-xaml-files-aka-removing-versioned-namespaces/

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2015 released an incorrect binding redirect in the config of the build service; TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.config.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation" 
                    publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
                    culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.9.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

There is no `Microsoft.TeamFoundation, Version=14.0.0.0`.

`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll` only existed up until TFS 2012, after which the namespaces in this dll were merged into `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll`.

I have raised a [Connect Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2508587/incorrect-binding-redirect-in-tfs-2015-tfsbuildservicehost-exe-config) with Microsoft. You can either update the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation` references in your template to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common`, or you remove/modify the redirect to the following.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation" 
                    publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
                    culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

The caveat here is that your are running the TFS 2015 build services on the same infrastructure you were running TFS 2012 (or at least have the same dependencies installed), the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll was distributed with Visual Studio 2012 and before.